# Wpf: How can i change the binding path of a gridview column in a listview to another column of a datatable at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, gridview

Here is a sample xaml code:

```
<listview>
    blah blah blah..
    ......................
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Date" Width="180" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Date}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=col1}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

here this binding path  **DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Date}**
/* Date is a column name of a sql data table which is binding */
Suppose this datatable has 3 column - col1, col2 and col3. What i want is to change the binding path of the second column of the listview (which is currently binding to col1) to col2 or col3 of this data table at runtime. That means when i run my program and click a button, the second column of the listview will automatically change.

C# code

```
        conn = new SqlCeConnection(constr);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM " + tablename + "";

            cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet(tablename);
            da.Fill(ds);
            sview.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView; //sview is the name of listview

            da.Update(ds);
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't change binding. Use view model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly MyModel _model;
    private bool _displayProperty1;

    public MyViewModel(MyModel model)
    {
        _model = model;
    }

    public bool DisplayProperty1 
    { 
        get { return _displayProperty1; }
        set
        {
            _displayProperty1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DisplayProperty1");
            OnPropertyChanged("PropertyToDisplay");
        }
    }

    public string PropertyToDisplay 
    { 
        get
        {
            return DisplayProperty1 ? _model.Property1 : _model.Property2;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PropertyToDisplay}" />
```

You can change `DisplayProperty1` either from toggle button, or using regular button + command. When you'll change it, data source for bound column will be switched from one property to another.